# Table Simulation Theory Query

Tags: simulation

I am looking at a question and associated solution for a simple Hand Simulation Table. I'm sorry this isn't a programming question, but probably on of logic.  The background to my question is to do with the question shown in the image.  It says that....  A customer arrives at the **end of every 3 minutes**...AND **serving takes 4 minutes**.  If the simulation table was run for 20 minutes using time-driven simulation, it would look like this...

[image]

My point of understanding is this...
When Master Clock reaches 06:00 hours, the solution example shows that Customers in Queue is now 1, where I put assume 0. To me, It isn't until Master Clock reaches 07:00 that we have our first customer in queue.

The interpretation of the question is important here, so i stress that the Customers arrive at the end of every 3 minutes and serving takes 4 minutes.    My own solution is posted below.  Which is right?

[image]

PS: Please note, the first column should show Master Clock (mins) not (hours). This is a typo error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was an error in the original solution. The new solution i've posted rectifies the error.